# "Instead of" Triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a customer.

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `cNic` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `cName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cAddress` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cTp` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cEmail` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `creditLimit` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CustomerStatus` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`cNic`)
)
```

When a new row is added to this customer table, If the `cNic` (primary key) of the new row is already in the customer table I want to do an update to the existing (old) row with the the other fields. (`Update customer set cName='NewName' where cNic = 'enteredNic'` ).

Otherwise (If the `cNic` is not in the table) insert a new row. I know I can do this in mssql using `instead of` triggers. Is there is a way to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL does not have instead of triggers, but it does have [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) and [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (see documentation).

Also see my answer to ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that worth notice is views in `MySQL` are updatable, meaning that your insert or update statement on views will automatically operate on your base table. Of course under the condition that your insert or update action won't cause any ambiguity.

For example you have a table `R(A, B)` which has one tuple `(1, 2)`. And the view `V(A)` is `(1)`. If you add `(10)` to `V`, it will cause ambiguity since `MySQL` doesn't know it should insert `(10, 1)` or `(10, 2)` or `(10, NULL)` in the base table.

More information [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-updatable-views.aspx)