# How to convert MSSQL Trigger to MySql Trigger for Instead of trigger that is used in MSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, triggers

How to convert MSSQL Trigger to MySql Trigger for Instead of trigger that is used in MSSQL

Is there any converting tool online to change this MSSQL trigger to MySql Trigger

What is the syntax that can be used for MYSQL for:
    INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

```
  /******Object: MYSQL TRIGGER.[T1_USERS]  Script Date: 13-Jul-2017 09:41:22 ******/

DROP TRIGGER  IF EXISTS T1_USERS;

CREATE TRIGGER T1_USERS ON USERS
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE
   @OLD_CODE                           varchar(10),
   @NEW_CODE                           varchar(10),
   @OLD_NAME                           varchar(40),
   @NEW_NAME                           varchar(40),
   @OLD_PASSWORD                       varchar(512),
   @NEW_PASSWORD                       varchar(512),
   @OLD_GROUP_CODE                     varchar(10),
   @NEW_GROUP_CODE                     varchar(10),
   @OLD_ACTIVE                         varchar(1),
   @NEW_ACTIVE                         varchar(1),
   @OLD_LOCKED                         varchar(1),
   @NEW_LOCKED                         varchar(1),
   @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG           varchar(1),
   @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG           varchar(1),
   @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS                 decimal(6, 0),
   @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS                 decimal(6, 0),
   @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE           datetime,
   @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE           datetime,
   @OLD_MDW_ID                         [varchar](20),
   @NEW_MDW_ID                         [varchar](20),
   @OLD_CHG_ID                         [varchar](20),
   @NEW_CHG_ID                         [varchar](20),
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE              [varchar](250),
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE              [varchar](250),
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE           [varchar](50),
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE           [varchar](50),
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER             [varchar](100),
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER             [varchar](100),
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME           [varchar](100),
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME           [varchar](100),
   @OLD_CREATED_ON                     [datetime],
   @NEW_CREATED_ON                     [datetime],
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE              [varchar](250),
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE              [varchar](250),
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE           [varchar](50),
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE           [varchar](50),
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER             [varchar](100),
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER             [varchar](100),
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME           [varchar](100),
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME           [varchar](100),
   @OLD_CHANGED_ON                     [datetime],
   @NEW_CHANGED_ON                     [datetime],
   @RowsInserted                       [integer],
   @RowsDeleted                        [integer],
   @RowsRecordID                       [integer],
   @Mode                               [varchar](1),
   @ChangeID                           [numeric],
   @ActionID                           [numeric],
   @Action                             [varchar](30),
   @Action1                            [varchar](30),
   @Action2                            [varchar](30),
   @PosCode                            [varchar](30),
   @mMachine                           [varchar](150),
   @mSessionID                         [decimal](9,0),
   @mAppUserCode                       [varchar](50),
   @mOSUser                            [varchar](50),
   @mAppUserName                       [varchar](150),
   @mModuleName                        [varchar](250)
BEGIN

SELECT @RowsInserted = COUNT(*) FROM Inserted
SELECT @RowsDeleted  = COUNT(*) FROM Deleted
SELECT @RowsRecordID = COUNT(*) FROM Inserted I, Deleted D WHERE (I.CODE=D.CODE)
SELECT * INTO #tempInserted FROM Inserted
SELECT * INTO #tempDeleted  FROM Deleted
SET @ActionID = NEXT VALUE FOR ACTION_ID_SEQ

SELECT 
   @mAppUserCode=APP_USERCODE,
   @mOSUser=OS_USER,
   @mAppUserName=APP_USERNAME,
   @mModuleName=MODULE_NAME,
   @mMachine=MACHINE,
   @mSessionID=SESSION_ID
FROM
   DB_SESSION_VIEW

IF (@RowsInserted>0) AND (@RowsDeleted=0)
   BEGIN
   UPDATE #tempInserted SET
      CREATED_BY_MODULE    = @mModuleName,
      CREATED_BY_USER_CODE = @mAppUserCode,
      CREATED_BY_OS_USER   = @mOSUser,
      CREATED_BY_USER_NAME = @mAppUserName,
      CREATED_ON           = GetDate()
   END
ELSE IF (@RowsInserted>0) AND (@RowsDeleted>0)
   BEGIN
   UPDATE #tempInserted SET
      CHANGED_BY_MODULE    = @mModuleName,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE = @mAppUserCode,
      CHANGED_BY_OS_USER   = @mOSUser,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME = @mAppUserName,
      CHANGED_ON           = GetDate()
   END

DECLARE InsertedCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT
      I.CODE, 
      I.NAME, 
      I.PASSWORD, 
      I.GROUP_CODE, 
      I.ACTIVE, 
      I.LOCKED, 
      I.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      I.NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      I.LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      I.MDW_ID,
      I.CHG_ID,
      I.CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      I.CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      I.CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      I.CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      I.CREATED_ON,
      I.CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      I.CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      I.CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      I.CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      I.CHANGED_ON
   FROM
      #tempInserted I
   WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.CODE FROM #tempDeleted D WHERE (I.CODE=D.CODE))

DECLARE UpdatedCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT
      I.CODE                            AS      NEW_CODE,
      I.NAME                            AS      NEW_NAME,
      I.PASSWORD                        AS      NEW_PASSWORD,
      I.GROUP_CODE                      AS      NEW_GROUP_CODE,
      I.ACTIVE                          AS      NEW_ACTIVE,
      I.LOCKED                          AS      NEW_LOCKED,
      I.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG            AS      NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG,
      I.NO_OF_ATTEMPTS                  AS      NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,
      I.LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE            AS      NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE,
      I.MDW_ID                          AS      NEW_MDW_ID,
      I.CHG_ID                          AS      NEW_CHG_ID,
      I.CREATED_BY_MODULE               AS      NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      I.CREATED_BY_USER_CODE            AS      NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      I.CREATED_BY_OS_USER              AS      NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      I.CREATED_BY_USER_NAME            AS      NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      I.CREATED_ON                      AS      NEW_CREATED_ON,
      I.CHANGED_BY_MODULE               AS      NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      I.CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE            AS      NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      I.CHANGED_BY_OS_USER              AS      NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      I.CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME            AS      NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      I.CHANGED_ON                      AS      NEW_CHANGED_ON,
      D.CODE                            AS      OLD_CODE,
      D.NAME                            AS      OLD_NAME,
      D.PASSWORD                        AS      OLD_PASSWORD,
      D.GROUP_CODE                      AS      OLD_GROUP_CODE,
      D.ACTIVE                          AS      OLD_ACTIVE,
      D.LOCKED                          AS      OLD_LOCKED,
      D.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG            AS      OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG,
      D.NO_OF_ATTEMPTS                  AS      OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,
      D.LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE            AS      OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE,
      D.MDW_ID                          AS      OLD_MDW_ID,
      D.CHG_ID                          AS      OLD_CHG_ID,
      D.CREATED_BY_MODULE               AS      OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      D.CREATED_BY_USER_CODE            AS      OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      D.CREATED_BY_OS_USER              AS      OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      D.CREATED_BY_USER_NAME            AS      OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      D.CREATED_ON                      AS      OLD_CREATED_ON,
      D.CHANGED_BY_MODULE               AS      OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      D.CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE            AS      OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      D.CHANGED_BY_OS_USER              AS      OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      D.CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME            AS      OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      D.CHANGED_ON                      AS      OLD_CHANGED_ON
   FROM
      #tempInserted I,
      #tempDeleted  D
   WHERE
      (I.CODE=D.CODE)

DECLARE DeletedCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT
      D.CODE, 
      D.NAME, 
      D.PASSWORD, 
      D.GROUP_CODE, 
      D.ACTIVE, 
      D.LOCKED, 
      D.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      D.NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      D.LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      D.MDW_ID,
      D.CHG_ID,
      D.CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      D.CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      D.CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      D.CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      D.CREATED_ON,
      D.CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      D.CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      D.CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      D.CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      D.CHANGED_ON
   FROM
      #tempDeleted D
   WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT I.CODE FROM #tempInserted I WHERE (D.CODE=I.CODE))

DELETE FROM USERS WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted D WHERE (USERS.CODE=D.CODE))

INSERT INTO USERS
   (
   CODE, 
   NAME, 
   PASSWORD, 
   GROUP_CODE, 
   ACTIVE, 
   LOCKED, 
   CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   MDW_ID,
   CHG_ID,
   CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   CREATED_ON,
   CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   CHANGED_ON
   )
SELECT
   CODE, 
   NAME, 
   PASSWORD, 
   GROUP_CODE, 
   ACTIVE, 
   LOCKED, 
   CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   MDW_ID,
   CHG_ID,
   CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   CREATED_ON,
   CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   CHANGED_ON
FROM
   #tempInserted

OPEN InsertedCursor
OPEN UpdatedCursor
OPEN DeletedCursor

SET  @Action  = 'INSERT'
SET  @Action1 = 'INSERT'
FETCH NEXT FROM InsertedCursor INTO
   @NEW_CODE, 
   @NEW_NAME, 
   @NEW_PASSWORD, 
   @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
   @NEW_ACTIVE, 
   @NEW_LOCKED, 
   @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   @NEW_MDW_ID,
   @NEW_CHG_ID,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @NEW_CREATED_ON,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @NEW_CHANGED_ON
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
   SET @ChangeID = NEXT VALUE FOR CHANGE_ID_SEQ
   INSERT INTO USERS_LOG
      (
      CHANGE_ID,
      ACTION,
      NEW_OLD,
      CODE, 
      NAME, 
      PASSWORD, 
      GROUP_CODE, 
      ACTIVE, 
      LOCKED, 
      CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      MDW_ID,
      CHG_ID,
      CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CREATED_ON,
      CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CHANGED_ON,
      ACTION_ID,
      CHG_DATE_TIME,
      CHG_USER_ID,
      CHG_MACHINE_NAME,
      CHG_SESSION_ID
      )
   VALUES
      (
      @ChangeID,
      @Action1,
      'NEW',
      @NEW_CODE, 
      @NEW_NAME, 
      @NEW_PASSWORD, 
      @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
      @NEW_ACTIVE, 
      @NEW_LOCKED, 
      @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @NEW_MDW_ID,
      @NEW_CHG_ID,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CREATED_ON,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CHANGED_ON,
      @ActionID,
      GetDate(),
      @mAppUserCode,
      @mMachine,
      @mSessionID
      )

   FETCH NEXT FROM InsertedCursor INTO
      @NEW_CODE, 
      @NEW_NAME, 
      @NEW_PASSWORD, 
      @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
      @NEW_ACTIVE, 
      @NEW_LOCKED, 
      @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @NEW_MDW_ID,
      @NEW_CHG_ID,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CREATED_ON,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CHANGED_ON
   END

SET  @Action = 'UPDATE'
FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatedCursor INTO
   @NEW_CODE, 
   @NEW_NAME, 
   @NEW_PASSWORD, 
   @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
   @NEW_ACTIVE, 
   @NEW_LOCKED, 
   @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   @NEW_MDW_ID,
   @NEW_CHG_ID,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @NEW_CREATED_ON,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @NEW_CHANGED_ON,
   @OLD_CODE, 
   @OLD_NAME, 
   @OLD_PASSWORD, 
   @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
   @OLD_ACTIVE, 
   @OLD_LOCKED, 
   @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   @OLD_MDW_ID,
   @OLD_CHG_ID,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @OLD_CREATED_ON,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @OLD_CHANGED_ON
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
   SET @ChangeID = NEXT VALUE FOR CHANGE_ID_SEQ
   IF (@OLD_CODE=@NEW_CODE)
      BEGIN
      SET  @Action1 = 'UPDATE'
      SET  @Action2 = 'UPDATE'
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET  @Action1 = 'DELETE'
      SET  @Action2 = 'INSERT'
      END

   INSERT INTO USERS_LOG
      (
      CHANGE_ID,
      ACTION,
      NEW_OLD,
      CODE, 
      NAME, 
      PASSWORD, 
      GROUP_CODE, 
      ACTIVE, 
      LOCKED, 
      CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      MDW_ID,
      CHG_ID,
      CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CREATED_ON,
      CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CHANGED_ON,
      ACTION_ID,
      CHG_DATE_TIME,
      CHG_USER_ID,  
      CHG_MACHINE_NAME,
      CHG_SESSION_ID
      )
   VALUES
      (
      @ChangeID,
      @Action1,
      'OLD',
      @OLD_CODE, 
      @OLD_NAME, 
      @OLD_PASSWORD, 
      @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
      @OLD_ACTIVE, 
      @OLD_LOCKED, 
      @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @OLD_MDW_ID,
      @OLD_CHG_ID,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CREATED_ON,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CHANGED_ON,
      @ActionID,
      GetDate(),
      @mAppUserCode,
      @mMachine,
      @mSessionID
      )
   INSERT INTO USERS_LOG
      (
      CHANGE_ID,
      ACTION,
      NEW_OLD,
      CODE, 
      NAME, 
      PASSWORD, 
      GROUP_CODE, 
      ACTIVE, 
      LOCKED, 
      CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      MDW_ID,
      CHG_ID,
      CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CREATED_ON,
      CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CHANGED_ON,
      ACTION_ID,
      CHG_DATE_TIME,
      CHG_USER_ID,
      CHG_MACHINE_NAME,
      CHG_SESSION_ID
      )
   VALUES
      (
      @ChangeID,
      @Action2,
      'NEW',
      @NEW_CODE, 
      @NEW_NAME, 
      @NEW_PASSWORD, 
      @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
      @NEW_ACTIVE, 
      @NEW_LOCKED, 
      @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @NEW_MDW_ID,
      @NEW_CHG_ID,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CREATED_ON,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CHANGED_ON,
      @ActionID,
      GetDate(),
      @mAppUserCode,
      @mMachine,
      @mSessionID
      )

   FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatedCursor INTO
      @NEW_CODE, 
      @NEW_NAME, 
      @NEW_PASSWORD, 
      @NEW_GROUP_CODE, 
      @NEW_ACTIVE, 
      @NEW_LOCKED, 
      @NEW_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @NEW_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @NEW_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @NEW_MDW_ID,
      @NEW_CHG_ID,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CREATED_ON,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @NEW_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @NEW_CHANGED_ON,
      @OLD_CODE, 
      @OLD_NAME, 
      @OLD_PASSWORD, 
      @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
      @OLD_ACTIVE, 
      @OLD_LOCKED, 
      @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @OLD_MDW_ID,
      @OLD_CHG_ID,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CREATED_ON,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CHANGED_ON
   END
SET  @Action  = 'DELETE'
SET  @Action1 = 'DELETE'
FETCH NEXT FROM DeletedCursor INTO
   @OLD_CODE, 
   @OLD_NAME, 
   @OLD_PASSWORD, 
   @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
   @OLD_ACTIVE, 
   @OLD_LOCKED, 
   @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
   @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
   @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
   @OLD_MDW_ID,
   @OLD_CHG_ID,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
   @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @OLD_CREATED_ON,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
   @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
   @OLD_CHANGED_ON
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
   SET @ChangeID = NEXT VALUE FOR CHANGE_ID_SEQ
   INSERT INTO USERS_LOG
      (
      CHANGE_ID,
      ACTION,
      NEW_OLD,
      CODE, 
      NAME, 
      PASSWORD, 
      GROUP_CODE, 
      ACTIVE, 
      LOCKED, 
      CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      MDW_ID,
      CHG_ID,
      CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CREATED_ON,
      CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      CHANGED_ON,
      ACTION_ID,
      CHG_DATE_TIME,
      CHG_USER_ID,
      CHG_MACHINE_NAME,
      CHG_SESSION_ID
      )
   VALUES
      (
      @ChangeID,
      @Action1,
      'OLD',
      @OLD_CODE, 
      @OLD_NAME, 
      @OLD_PASSWORD, 
      @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
      @OLD_ACTIVE, 
      @OLD_LOCKED, 
      @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @OLD_MDW_ID,
      @OLD_CHG_ID,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CREATED_ON,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CHANGED_ON,
      @ActionID,
      GetDate(),
      @mAppUserCode,
      @mMachine,
      @mSessionID
      )

   FETCH NEXT FROM DeletedCursor INTO
      @OLD_CODE, 
      @OLD_NAME, 
      @OLD_PASSWORD, 
      @OLD_GROUP_CODE, 
      @OLD_ACTIVE, 
      @OLD_LOCKED, 
      @OLD_CHANGE_PASSWORD_FLAG, 
      @OLD_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS, 
      @OLD_LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, 
      @OLD_MDW_ID,
      @OLD_CHG_ID,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CREATED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CREATED_ON,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_MODULE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_OS_USER,
      @OLD_CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME,
      @OLD_CHANGED_ON
   END

CLOSE DeletedCursor
CLOSE InsertedCursor
CLOSE UpdatedCursor

DEALLOCATE DeletedCursor
DEALLOCATE InsertedCursor
DEALLOCATE UpdatedCursor

END
GO
/********          *********/
```

Comment: Start by reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469614/instead-of-triggers-in-mysql

Comment: That's a lot of code can you skinny it down to the essentials?

Comment: I just want to create an audit table, the entries in audit table must be inserted by the trigger , ie if I have  got USER  table then  i have audit table called USER_LOG in which i will add all the insert and update and delete entries

Comment: Try using: http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: I tried that(http://www.sqlines.com/online) it did not help

Comment: There is no direct equivalent to an `instead of`-trigger in mysql. For a basic audit table you can use (several) triggers, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357483/creating-triggers-to-add-the-data-into-audit-table). You will have to adept your app code to completely replicate what your `instead of`-trigger does (see Alex's link). At first glance, you need to add `on duplicate key` in your app whereever you `insert` data, and code to check if the new `code` exists (e.g. add error handling) whenever you `update` the `code`-value for a user (if that happens at all).